# How to extract data from json where parameter has white space character

Tags: java, json, jayway

I have json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Name1",
    "address": "City1\nCountry1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Name2",
    "address": "City2 Country2"
  }
]
```

And I am using jayway library to extract "name" using "address". I want to parameterize the "address" using jpath

```
$.*[?(@.address=='{address}')].name
```

However, as you can see in json, first address has "\n" on it. Is there a way like normalize spacing for it so whenever I use jpath

```
$.*[?(@.address=='City1 Country1')].name
```

the value will still be extracted

Comment: I'm not sure how you are reading may be from file or API. convert JSON to string if not already a string then replace all \n's with space " ". If you can post a sample code of what you have tried then we can suggest few approaches

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's the workaround I am doing right now, from API response -> convert to string -> response.replace("\\n"," "). However, I am curious if we have solution like with selenium xpath locator which uses "normalize-space()"

Comment: I hope the answer provided some insights.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, a possible JSON-Path soltution is to use the contains operator for both parts:

```
$..[?(@.address contains 'City1' && @.address contains 'Country1')].name
```

However, this is not the same as a `==` comparison and could theoretically produce false positives.

Another option is to use the regex filter `=~`. Using it gives you full control and the ability to only match what you want; since you have a newline we need to inline [(?s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html) to make `.*` match any character including newlines.

```
$..[?(@.address =~ /(?s)City1.*Country1/i)].name
```